# Best possible estimate for $n$th prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

We all know the $n$th prime can be approximated by.  $nln(n)$    by Prime number theorem.
We also got inequalities for the estimate .

But my question is what is the best possible estimate for $n$th prime under all the necessary strong assumptions like Riemann hypothesis?

Comment: Isn't the answer that "The best possible estimate of $p_n$ is $p_n$"? As a statistical estimator, it's pretty much optimal.

Comment: With RH the estimate is (claimed to be)  with $n_0 \approx 3.9\cdot 10^{31}$, see the duplicate.

Comment: A "best estimate" is given by inverting the exact formula for $\pi(x)$ given by the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: @renus can you give a detailed form of the possible 'inverse' of $π(x)$?